# HID-compliant touchscreen NOT working Ubuntu 14 & 16

Tags: drivers, touchscreen, multi-touch

Ive been searching this site for help with a touchscreen issue I am having through using Ubuntu 14. I noticed that there are a few users on the site having the same particular problem that I also am with the same machines. I am using an HP envy x360 and my touchscreen functions properly using Windows but can barely even be detected (using lsusb, xinput, lsmod, etc.) by the Ubuntu OS and is completely non-responsive even after manually enabling hid-multitouch and other recommended fixes Ive found on the site.

A different user believes to have identified the device to be an ELAN0732 I2C touchscreen controller but bc it is so difficult to find this ID anywhere within my system I cannot confirm this.

My question is have anyone had any breakthroughs in success with finding a solution to this issue? I wish it was as easy as the NetworkManager wifi fix by blacklisting the acer_wmi module which is also a bug associated with this machine, but of course it is not as simple.

It would be great to hear that progress was made on this issue .. if not someone please let me know that I should stop searching because I have been at debugging this problem for about 6 days now. haha.

Thank you very much in advance !